# Set theoretic complete intersections in toric varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, etale-cohomology, hodge-theory, toric-varieties

Is it expected that every smooth projective variety over the complex numbers, is a set-theoretic complete intersection into a smooth projective toric variety?

Is there an example of a smooth projective variety that isn't?

Comment: Set-theoretic complete intersections satisfy some Lefschetz-type theorems. For instance, any variety of dimension at least 2 with $H^1(X,O_X)\neq 0$ (e.g., abelian surfaces) cannot be a set-theoretic complete intersection.